# リンクサーバの文字コードについて

Tags: sql-server, oracle

お世話になります。
SQLServerのリンクサーバ機能を使用し、OracleのDBを参照しようと考えております。
Oracleで参照したデータをSQLServer側に登録する際に、文字コードの変換は自動で行われるものなのでしょうか。
Nプレフィックスをつける必要があるのでしょうか。

何か対応する必要があるのかがわからずにいます。
教えていただけますと幸いです。

下記、各DBで使用している文字コード、データ型です。
■SQLServer 2012 RTM 
文字コード：JapaneseCI_AS
データ型：nvarchar,char

■Oracle Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition 
文字コード：JA16EUC
データ型：char

よろしくお願い致します。